# Polling with Redux-saga not working on first time invoke

Tags: redux-saga

_saga file changes :

```
export function* pollStuffSaga() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      yield call(() => Axios({ url: 'http://abcd' }));
      // const items = handleResponse(response); // The problem was inside this function
      yield put({type:"UPLOAD_DONE",isPolling:false});
      yield delay(3000);
    } catch (e) {
      // yield put(onFetchStuffFailure(e));
      yield put({type:"UPLOAD_ERROR",isPolling:false});
      yield delay(3000);
    }
  }
}

function* pollWatcherSaga() {
  while (true) {
    yield take("UPLOAD_SET_STATUS");
    yield race([call(pollStuffSaga), take("UPLOAD_DONE"),take("UPLOAD_ERROR")]);
  }
}
```

When I call dispatch from component it calls UPLOAD_SET_STATUS but never invokes polling but I try to invoke same action again it works perfectly. Please help me if I'm doing anything wrong here.

```
 dispatch({
      type:'UPLOAD_SET_STATUS',
      isPolling:true
    })
```

[image]

Blog reference : https://bigbite.net/insights/polling-with-redux/

Comment: The non-terminating `while(true)` loop in `pollWatcherSaga` calls `pollStuffSaga` which also has a non-terminating `while(true)` loop. Given that `pollStuffSaga` will never complete, using it in a race also seems incorrect.

Comment: could you please guide me how to resolve this ?